# What to do when one of implementations requires a bit more data

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am thinking what is the right way to deal with a situation like this: I have an interface IService that looks like this:

```
class Configuration
{
    public int Min { get; set; } 
    public int Max { get; set; }     
}

interface IService
{
    int Calculate(int userId, Configuration configuration)
}
```

I have, let's say, 5 classes that implement this interface and they work well.
One day I have to implement a 6th service, but this one is a little bit different. To do its job, a new service needs configuration like this:

```
class ExtendedConfiguration : Configuration
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }     
}
```

My new service could look like this:

```
class NewService : IService
{
    public int Calculate(int userId, Configuration configuration)
    {
        var extendedConfig = configuration as ExtendedConfiguration;
        //Calculating and returning result using extendedConfig...
    }
}
```

It seems to be fine, the service would work.
BUT, I don't like the fact, that Calculate method signature requires Configuration object, while in reality ExtendedConfiguration is needed - otherwise it will not be able to do the calculation (and will throw exception).

Is there a better way of writing this code?

Comment: How about making the interface generic? `IService<TConfig>` could then take a `TConfig configuration`parameter in the Calculate method.

Comment: You could achieve this by using generics in your interface. Something like `int Calculate(int userId, T configuration)` with `T` constrained to be of type `Configuration` at the interface-definition-level.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError - generics are nice, but generally when you make one thing generic, suddenly you cause an avalanche of  most of your classes becoming generic. I thought about it before, I even tried to do that, but the effect was like I said - almost EVERYTHING became generic, which introduces unnecessary complication (harder to understand for people new to the codebase). My services are instantiated through Factory class, which expects a collection of IService implementations. If my services start to use generic interfaces, my Factory will break, it expects IService, not IService<T>

Comment: Is every service have their own `Configuration` class?

Comment: "(and will throw exception)." FYI `configuration as ExtendedConfiguration` does not throw an exception. It returns `null` if the casting failed. you can check for it.

Comment: @D-Shih No, the one I presented is enough for most of them. Only some of them  need more configuration and have their own Configuration classes

Comment: @MongZhu I know, I raher meant that Calculate method will not be able to do its job and I would throw an exception explicitly. Something like (throw new Exception("Configuration should be of type ExtendedConfiguration")

Comment: The problem of this question is `Is there a better way of writing this code?` depends on a lot of other factors, you mention factories and not liking generics. I kind of think you have answered your own question. the only other things i can think of is, making `IServiceExtended`, and using composition. however i dont think its going to solve anymore problems then it creates and It all really depends on how far you want to go down the rabbit hole

Comment: Shouldn't the configuration be a property of the service? Or is it just more like parameters? If it could be in the service, then you would be able to have IService which contains the method with the int parameter, and an IService<T> that would provide the configuration in the specialized type. Then your services have to implement both (maybe a common interface). Would that work for you?

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError That's an interesting idea. The configuration would be passed in the constructor of the service, instead of Calculate method. I think IService<T> would not be necessary in such case.

Answer (score 4):

> that Calculate method signature requires Configuration object, while in reality ExtendedConfiguration is needed

As already mentioned you could aim for a generic solution of your restriction problem. Define the interface with a generic parameter and constrain it to be of type `Configuration`:

```
interface IService<T> where T : Configuration
{
    int Calculate(int userId, T configuration)
}
```

Then your old services could still look like they used to be:

```
class OldService : IService<Configuration>
{
    public int Calculate(int userId, Configuration configuration)
    {       
        return (configuration.Min + configuration.Max) * 2;
    }
}
```

and in the `NewService` you can specify that the input parameter has to be of type `ExtendedConfiguration` :

```
class NewService : IService<ExtendedConfiguration>
{
    public int Calculate(int userId, ExtendedConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string accessHereTheExtendedVersion = configuration.Filter;
        return (configuration.Min + configuration.Max) / 2;
    }
}
```

This is not really the answer to your exact question:

> Is there a better way of writing this code?

But it is a different approach of how this problem can be solved. Whether it suits your context and situation, you have to test it.

Comment: It is one of ideas that I tried before asking this question on SO. Still, thanks for presenting it nicely, might be useful for others. Personally I'm not a big fan of generics, usually when you make one thing generic, sudenly many other things also have to become generic.

Comment: Upvote, seems like a sane and straight forward and modern approach

Comment: @Loreno "usually when you make one thing generic, sudenly many other things also have to become generic." I know such cases. Another approach could be a strategy pattern. (I guess this is what [DeveloperExceptionError 14 ] spoke about) But I don't really know whether it fits your construct of services

Comment: @Loreno how different is the usage of `Configuration` between the services? do you use it only in `Calculation` ? or also in other methods?

Comment: @Loreno actually without generics you are always left with the ambiguity that a normal `Configuration` can be inserted. This is usually solved using polymorphism. I think for this you would need an overrideable method in `Configuration` which will be overridden in `ExtendedConfiguration` and it has to behave differently depending on the type of configuration. Then you can use it as a property inside the service and inside the calculate method

Answer (score 1):

I guess it comes down to the definition of "better". I don't personally like the assumptive cast to ExtendedConfiguration. Not only do you outsource the problem of how to populate that configuration to somewhere else, but now your code will crash if I send the wrong implementation. So something outside needs to know that you need this specific implementation, and populate the setting values accordingly. In the world of code smells, it is hardly a capital offence, but I would invert that problem.

Rather than provide a configuration to the service, provide a configuration provider:
(using [C#7 ValueTuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/))

```
public enum ValueType
{
    ReturnedConfigured,
    NotConfiguredReturnedDefault,
    InvalidConfigurationReturnedDefault
}

public interface IConfigurationProvider
{
    (T result, ValueType resultType) GetSetting<T>(string serviceName, string settingKey, T defaultValue);
}

public interface IService
{
    int Calculate(int userId, IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider);
}
```

You can consume this as follows:

```
public class NewService : IService
{
    public int Calculate(int userId, IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    {
        (int min, _) = configurationProvider.GetSetting(nameof(NewService), "Min", -1);
        (int max, _) = configurationProvider.GetSetting(nameof(NewService), "Max", Int32.MaxValue);
        (string filter, ValueType filterConfigResponse) = configurationProvider.GetSetting(nameof(NewService), "Filter", string.Empty);
        if (filterConfigResponse!=ValueType.ReturnedConfigured)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Oh no! Where's my filter?", nameof(configurationProvider));
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(NewService)},min={min}, max={max}, filter={filter}");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of an IConfigurationProvider that you might inject into a unit test

```
public class FakeConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider
{
    public (T result, ValueType resultType) GetSetting<T>(string serviceName, string settingKey, T defaultValue)
    {
        switch (settingKey)
        {
            case "Min":
                {
                    return (result: (T)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(T)), resultType: ValueType.ReturnedConfigured);
                }
            case "Max":
                {
                    return (result: (T)Convert.ChangeType(42, typeof(T)), resultType: ValueType.ReturnedConfigured);
                }
            case "Filter":
                {
                    return (result: (T)Convert.ChangeType("Hello World", typeof(T)), resultType: ValueType.ReturnedConfigured);
                }
            default:
                {
                    return (result: defaultValue, resultType: ValueType.NotConfiguredReturnedDefault);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

From here it is pretty straight forward to imagine other configuration providers for pulling the settings from app.Config or a database table or a Uri or however you choose to have them stored.

Comment: Your solution is.. complicated. Probably it's very good and follows some good practices, but personally I am not able to quickly understand such code when I look at it.

Comment: @Loreno, if you find my solution complicated then perhaps I haven't explained it well enough. What part are you struggling to understand?

Comment: no, it's not your fault at all. I just find it hard to think in such abstractions, which I really should improve on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find this solution terrible; algorithms which try to treat objects in an inheritance hierarchy uniformly come with the downside that at some point you'll need to set or check certain traits of objects *at run time*. The reason is exactly what you experience: It's rare that one solution fits all if you get to the fringe cases.

An alternative apporach to checking the type would be to make `Configuration`, well, *configurable.* The typical approaches are

- Inheritance: `Configuration` defines extra virtual methods (e.g. pre-processing, extra-processing or post-processing ;-)) which are empty but can be filled with life in derived classes. The calling code doesn't have to know the exact type, it just stupidly calls these functions in the proper order, and whatever that particular class defines them to do gets done.
- Injection: The behavior of `Configure` objects is configured at run time by setting members which "know how to do" things. The calculation is performed using information or actions defined in these "agents".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no problem. As mentioned before, the casting is failed.

You don't want to generic type approach. Maybe you can create an instance ExtConfigclass and assign config's values to it.

```
class NewService : IService
{
    public int Calculate(int userId, Configuration configuration)
    {
        var extendedConfig = new ExtendedConfiguration {
            Max = configuration.Max,
            Min=configuration.Min
        };


        return e.Max - e.Min;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. ExtendedConfiguration has MORE data than Configuration. If someone used Configuration in Calculate method, the method will fail - it REQUIRES ExtendedConfiguration, since it contains the required data (string Filter)